# Bluetooth Audio becomes stuttering while downloading or heavy use in network data via ethernet

Tags: fedora, audio, bluetooth, pipewire

I had this problem with Manjaro on my macbookpro 2016.

Now I am having same problem with Fedora 35 on PC. I googled it and some forums says it causes due to 2.4 GHz issues with Wifi. But now I am using a wired Ethernet connection and it is still happening.

It doesn’t matter if the source I'm playing is local or online - the audio becomes laggy when I am downloading files while playing the audio.

I am using also using MX Master2s.

```
pipewire on both manjaro and fedora

Sony WH1000XM3 ( LDAC )

Orico Bluetooth 5.0 Adapter on PC USB 3.2 Port
```

**inxi -Fzx** Result:

```
System:    Kernel: 5.15.6-200.fc35.x86_64 x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 2.37-10.fc35 Desktop: GNOME 41.1
           Distro: Fedora release 35 (Thirty Five)
Machine:   Type: Desktop Mobo: Gigabyte model: B550 GAMING X V2 serial: <superuser required> UEFI: American Megatrends LLC.
           v: F14e date: 10/13/2021
CPU:       Info: 6-Core model: AMD Ryzen 5 5600G with Radeon Graphics bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Zen 3 rev: 0 cache:
           L2: 3 MiB
           flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm bogomips: 93427
           Speed: 2687 MHz min/max: 1400/3900 MHz boost: enabled Core speeds (MHz): 1: 2687 2: 2046 3: 3275 4: 2598 5: 2462
           6: 1900 7: 2232 8: 2094 9: 2085 10: 1960 11: 1786 12: 2334
Graphics:  Device-1: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Cezanne vendor: Gigabyte driver: amdgpu v: kernel bus-ID: 05:00.0
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: loaded: amdgpu,ati unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,vesa
           resolution: 2560x1080
           OpenGL: renderer: AMD RENOIR (DRM 3.42.0 5.15.6-200.fc35.x86_64 LLVM 13.0.0) v: 4.6 Mesa 21.3.1
           direct render: Yes
Audio:     Device-1: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel
           bus-ID: 05:00.1
           Device-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 17h HD Audio vendor: Gigabyte driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel
           bus-ID: 05:00.6
           Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.15.6-200.fc35.x86_64 running: yes
           Sound Server-2: PipeWire v: 0.3.40 running: yes
Network:   Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet vendor: Gigabyte driver: r8169 v: kernel
           port: f000 bus-ID: 03:00.0
           IF: enp3s0 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
           IF-ID-1: docker0 state: down mac: <filter>
Bluetooth: Device-1: Realtek Bluetooth Radio type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8 bus-ID: 5-2:2
           Report: rfkill ID: hci0 rfk-id: 0 state: up address: see --recommends
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 476.94 GiB used: 72.54 GiB (15.2%)
           ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: A-Data model: SX8200PNP size: 476.94 GiB temp: 31.9 C
Partition: ID-1: / size: 360 GiB used: 72.53 GiB (20.1%) fs: btrfs dev: /dev/nvme0n1p6
           ID-2: /boot/efi size: 1022 MiB used: 13.8 MiB (1.4%) fs: vfat dev: /dev/nvme0n1p5
Swap:      ID-1: swap-1 type: partition size: 10.09 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) dev: /dev/nvme0n1p7
           ID-2: swap-2 type: zram size: 8 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) dev: /dev/zram0
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 38.0 C mobo: 25.0 C gpu: amdgpu temp: 32.0 C
           Fan Speeds (RPM): cpu: 888 mobo: 500
           Power: 12v: N/A 5v: N/A 3.3v: N/A vbat: 3.07
Info:      Processes: 393 Uptime: 4m Memory: 13.56 GiB used: 2.76 GiB (20.3%) Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers:
           gcc: 11.2.1 Packages: 10 note: see --pkg Shell: Zsh v: 5.8 inxi: 3.3.09
```

Comment: same thing happening to me, but completely different setup. Linux mint 21, intel Bluetooth adapter, and AptX HD as the codec. very easy to reproduce though, my uneducated opinion is may have something to do with priority/scheduling.